# How to try-catch errors from a query executed on a linked server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, t-sql

I'm looking to query a linked server in a stored procedure to set a variable with results that will continue even if the linked server throws an error and set the variable to an arbitrary `datetime`.

I've tried to wrap the declarative query in a try catch statement.

```
BEGIN TRY
SELECT @dttemp  = maxdt FROM OPENQUERY(DEV,'SELECT MAX(MODIFIED_DATE) as maxdt FROM ODB.DEV ')
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    SET @dttemp = cast(-53690 as datetime)
end catch
END CATCH
```

When I execute the stored procedure I get this erro:

```
OLE DB provider "OraOLEDB.Oracle" for linked server "DEV" returned message "ORA-12170: TNS:Connect timeout occurred".
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Linked server error not caught by TRY-CATCH](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/36178/linked-server-error-not-caught-by-try-catch) (on [dba](http://dba.stackexchange.com))?

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/36189/44761

Comment: Lol indeed. That should more than answer the OP's question here. :)